Closed form for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\ln(e^{2/(n(n+1))} + 1) - \ln(2))$?
Inspired by this :
Asymptotics for $f(z) = (z-1) \prod_n \frac{2}{z^{1/a_n}+1}$ with $1/a_1 + 1/a_2 + 1/a_3 + ... = 1.$
$$f(z) = (z-1) ([2 / (z^{1/a_1} + 1)] [2 / (z^{1/a_2} + 1)][2 / (z^{1/a_3} + 1)][2 / (z^{1/a_4} + 1)][2 / (z^{1/a_5} + 1)]...)$$
and the conjecture there :
For instance if $a_n = n(n+1)$ do we get
$$f(z) = O(\exp(\sqrt\ln(z))) $$
?
I considered
$$F(z) = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{1/a_n} + 1}{2} $$
Then I wanted a taylor series for it ;
$$F(e^z) = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{z/a_n} + 1}{2} $$
$$G(z) = \ln(F(e^z)) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\ln(e^{z/a_n} + 1) - \ln(2))$$
what is pretty close to a taylor series.
However the radius is problematic since $\ln(z+1)$ has radius $1$.
So the question here is, what is a good asymptotic for
$$G(z) = \ln(F(e^z)) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\ln(e^{z/(n(n+1))} + 1) - \ln(2))$$
And in particular I wonder
Is there a closed form for
$$G(2) = \ln(F(e^2)) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\ln(e^{2/(n(n+1))} + 1) - \ln(2))$$
Many series expansions for log and exp might be useful here.
I understand that maybe questions should be split up or merged, so I am open to such suggestions.

Too long for a comment
I do not know if a closed form exists for
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\log
   \left(e^{\frac{2}{n (n+1)}}+1\right)-\log(2)\right)$$ but we can have very good approximations.
Consider first
$$\log
   \left(e^{\frac{2}{a}}+1\right)-\log(2)=\sum _{m=1}^{\infty }\frac{2^{m-1} \, E_{m-1}(1)}{m\, (m-1)!\,a^m} $$ where appear Euler numbers.
This is then
$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{2 a^2}-\frac{1}{12a^4}+
\frac{1}{45 a^6}-\frac{17}{2520 a^8}+O\left(\frac{1}{a^{10}}\right)$$
Make $a=n(n+1)$ and perform the summations.
Limited to the above terms, the result is
$$\frac{9957}{280}-\frac{1913 \pi ^2}{630}-\frac{43
   \pi ^4}{1050}-\frac{139 \pi
   ^6}{297675}-\frac{17 \pi ^8}{11907000}$$ which is
$\color{red}{1.1399}78$
Using more terms, say up to $O\left(\frac{1}{a^{20}}\right)$, the result would be $\color{red}{1.1399800702}46$
